# Call to undefined function move() in laravel

Tags: php, post

Hi I am getting an image from a mobile and try to move it to a folder for almacernarlo. The problem that I get an error when I try to move it.

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Call to undefined function move()
```

My code:

```
    public function subirImagenes($idServicio){
    //$file_path = "uploads/";
    //dd(public_path());
    $path = public_path().'/servicios/1';//.$idServicio;
    /*$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }*/
    if($_FILES){
        //$file = $_FILES['file'];
        //move_uploaded_file($file, $file_path);
        //$fileContents = file_get_contents($file["tmp_name"]);
        //print_r($fileContents);

        $file = Input::file('file');
        if($file>move($path, '1')){
            $array = array('Message' => 'Imagen Movida', 'Code' => '202');

        }else{
            $array = array('Error' => 'InvalidArgumentError' , 'Code' => '404', 'Message' => 'Error interno');

        }

        return Response::json($array);

    }
}
```

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a typo:

```
$file>move($path, '1')
```

Should be:

```
$file->move($path, '1')
```

You want to call `$file->move()` rather than compare `$file` with `move()`